# Detect Attachments in Email

Tags: google-apps-script

I am scanning through each email in my spam folder. If the message contains an attachment, I would like to delete it.  Obviously this piece of code is not working.

How do you determine if an email contains an email? Is there something like msg.hasAttachments that can be used?

```
if (msg.getAttachments() = true) {
   console.log('Attachments Delete')
   console.log(i)
   Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', msg.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific "has" method, but you can use GmailApp's [`getAttachments()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getattachmentsoptions) returns an array with all the attachments objects, so you can just check its `length`.

```
  if (msg.getAttachments().length > 0){
    //has attachment, do something
  }
```

Even better, you could just use [`GmailApp.search()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)) and have Apps Script do that work for you. The search terms support checking for attachments:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('in:spam has:attachment');
```

##### Reference:

- [Class GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message)
- [Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)